# How do I install the touch core apps on 15.10 desktop?

Tags: 15.10, core-apps

What is the best way to install the touch core apps (terminal, file manager, music, etc.) on Ubuntu 15.10 desktop?
I am aware that there were already similar questions asked but the answers (e.g. the daily PPA) won't work for 15.10.
BTW I'm looking for a native installation, not inside an emulator or virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

First add the PPA to your Ubuntu 15.10 system:

```
sudo apt-get add-repository ppa:ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/daily
```

Then update the cache:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Example of installing music core app:

```
sudo apt-get install music-app
```